# Xamarin.Forms bind default value to DisplayPromptAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, popup

Is it possible to `DisplayPromptAsync` :

```
await DisplayPromptAsync("", "DEFAULT VALUE IS:", "ОК", "CANCEL","PLACEHOLDER");
```

add a default value?

For example I want to give a suggestion e-mail when user opens the DisplayPrompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is a parameter for this in the latest version

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> DisplayPromptAsync (
    string title, string message, string accept = "OK", 
    string cancel = "Cancel", string placeholder = default, 
    int maxLength = -1, Xamarin.Forms.Keyboard keyboard = default, 
    string initialValue = "");
```

use `initialValue`